# How to send mail for the every failed HTTP Request Sampler in JMETER?

Tags: automation, jmeter

I planned to create a Test Plan in my JMeter like below

Test Plan
Thread Group

```
HTTP Request Sampler 1
HTTP Request Sampler 2
HTTP Request Sampler 3
HTTP Request Sampler 4
HTTP Request Sampler 5
HTTP Request Sampler 6
HTTP Request Sampler 7
HTTP Request Sampler 8
```

> If Controller condition
>  ${__groovy(vars.get("JMeterThread.last_sample_ok").equals("false"),)}

*SMTP Sampler*

I would like to run the test 24/7. If one (or more) HTTP Request Sampler returns an error for whatever reason, then execute the SMTP sampler and send an email to me.

I want to check the condition for every sampler 1-8. But now if HTTP Request Sampler 4 and HTTP Request Sampler 8 is failed, JMeter only sends an email for HTTP Request Sampler 8.

If none of the HTTP Request Sampler returns an error, I want to send an email to me. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter executes Samplers upside down therefore given you have your If Controller only after `HTTP Request Sampler 8` - it will check **only HTTP Request Sampler 8 result**, previous failures will be silently ignored.

The solutions are in:

1. Copy and paste your If Controller to appear after each and every [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler you want to check
2. Basically the same as point 1 but using [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) instead of copying and pasting the If Controller
3. Replace this If Controller and SMTP Sampler combination with a single [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor), the condition you have already and the code to send a email can be found i.e. in [Send Email.groovy](https://gist.github.com/quchie/3e02c5d5df8de804e8e0) file. PostProcessors act according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) so a single instance will be applied to all Samplers on its level.